# Problems converting an Oracle plsql stored procedure call to C# (invalid array bind size)

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I need convert a call to a stored procedure that we are using in PL/SQL to c# code using odp.net12.

The stored procedure gets some parameters of a custom types.

This is my stored procedure call:

```
DECLARE
  P_SCODSERIE    VARCHAR2(3);
  P_SCODUSER     VARCHAR2(30);
  P_SMODACESS    VARCHAR2(8);
  P_SVETCODOBS   LINEUP.PCK_PIR_TYPES.VT_ARRAY_STRING;
  P_SVETDSCCOMPL LINEUP.PCK_PIR_TYPES.VT_ARRAY_FORMULA;
  P_NVETITEM     LINEUP.PCK_PIR_TYPES.VT_ARRAY_INT;
  R_NCODERROR    NUMBER;
BEGIN
  P_SCODSERIE := NULL;
  P_SCODUSER := 'TSR';
  P_SMODACESS := '00000001';
  P_SVETCODOBS(1) := '03';
  P_SVETDSCCOMPL(1) := 'comments about the item';
  P_NVETITEM(1) := 1;

  LINEUP.PCK_PIR_REQUEST_CMP.INSERTORDERCMP(
          P_SCODSERIE => P_SCODSERIE,
          P_SCODUSER => P_SCODUSER,
          P_SMODACESS => P_SMODACESS,
          P_SVETCODOBS => P_SVETCODOBS,
          P_SVETDSCCOMPL => P_SVETDSCCOMPL,
          P_NVETITEM => P_NVETITEM,
          R_NCODERROR => R_NCODERROR );
END;
/
```

When we convert this call to a C# code using odp.net, I'm getting an error

```
System.InvalidOperationException: OracleParameter.ArrayBindSize
```

but I can not find what my error on parameters.

**My C# code:**

```
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand objCmd
    = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand();

objCmd.Connection = (Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection) conn;
objCmd.CommandText = "LINEUP.PCK_PIR_REQUEST_CMP.INSERTORDERCMP";
objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
objCmd.BindByName = true;


objCmd.Parameters
      .Add("P_SCODSERIE", Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.Varchar2).Direction
      = ParameterDirection.Input;

objCmd.Parameters["P_SCODSERIE"].Value = null;


objCmd.Parameters
      .Add("P_SCODUSER ", Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.Varchar2).Direction
      = ParameterDirection.Input;

objCmd.Parameters["P_SCODUSER "].Value = "TSR";


objCmd.Parameters
      .Add("P_SMODACESS", Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.Varchar2).Direction
      = ParameterDirection.Input;

objCmd.Parameters["P_SMODACESS"].Value = "00000001";


Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter strVetCodObs
    = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter("P_SVETCODOBS", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input);

strVetCodObs.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;

strVetCodObs.Value = new String[1] { "03" };

strVetCodObs.Size = 1;

strVetCodObs.UdtTypeName = "LINEUP.PCK_PIR_TYPES.VT_ARRAY_STRING";

objCmd.Parameters.Add(strVetCodObs);


Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter strVetDescCompl
    = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter("P_SVETDSCCOMPL", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input);

strVetDescCompl.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;

strVetDescCompl.Value = new String[1] { "comments about the item" };

strVetDescCompl.Size = 1;

strVetDescCompl.UdtTypeName = "LINEUP.PCK_PIR_TYPES.VT_ARRAY_FORMULA";

objCmd.Parameters.Add(strVetDescCompl);


Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter nVetItem
    = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter("P_NVETITEM", OracleDbType.Decimal, ParameterDirection.Input);

nVetItem.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;

nVetItem.Value = new Int32[1] { 1 };

nVetItem.Size = 1;

nVetItem.UdtTypeName = "LINEUP.PCK_PIR_TYPES.VT_ARRAY_INT";

objCmd.Parameters.Add(nVetItem);

objCmd.Parameters
      .Add("R_NCODERRO", Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.Decimal).Direction
      = ParameterDirection.Output;


if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open) {
   conn.Open();
}

objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem (I think) is on this line:

```
objCmd.CommandText = "LINEUP.PCK_PIR_REQUEST_CMP.INSERTORDERCMP";
```

In later lines of code, you are binding C# variables by name to the statement you defined in the CommandText - the part you missed was to define the bind variables in it. You need to change that line to be something like:

```
objCmd.CommandText = "LINEUP.PCK_PIR_REQUEST_CMP.INSERTORDERCMP(
  P_SCODSERIE => :P_SCODSERIE,
  P_SCODUSER => :P_SCODUSER ,
  P_SMODACESS=> :P_SMODACESS,
  P_SVETCODOBS => :P_SVETCODOBS,
  P_SVETDSCCOMPL => :P_SVETDSCCOMPL,
  P_NVETITEM => :P_NVETITEM,
  R_NCODERROR => :R_NCODERROR 
)";
```

Then the code:

```
objCmd.Parameters["P_SCODSERIE"].Value = null;
```

Will see substitute the values 'null' for the placeholder in your statement called ':P_SCODSERIE'.

Comment: Tks, Stephen. But o dont need declare the procedure parameters in the call os C#, I have anothers codes with single OracleDbType(ex. varchar2) that i not declare the parameters and the code run without problems. However I'll do a test with your suggestion

Comment: I did a bit of googling and I think you are correct. I've never seen any odp.net code before - its different to how database calls are usually made from JDBC and other languages I know.